# RabbitMQ closing AMQP connection with error {handshake_timeout,frame_header}

Tags: asp.net, .net, rabbitmq

We have two dotnet applications that publish and subscribe to RabbitMQ respectively. Our developers tested it locally and they work fine on their workstation (launch through Visual Studio). However, when we build them into container and run them, RabbitMQ logs will show the following error messages:

```
2022-11-01 09:29:15.998692+00:00 [info] <0.1560.868> accepting AMQP connection <0.1560.868>
2022-11-01 09:31:22.599983+00:00 [error] <0.2112.868> closing AMQP connection <0.2112.868>
2022-11-01 09:31:22.599983+00:00 [error] <0.2112.868> {handshake_timeout,frame_header}
```

And below is the error message on our dotnet container:

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.PossibleAuthenticationFailureException: Possibly caused by authentication failure
---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Library, code=541, text='Unexpected Exception', classId=0, methodId=0, cause=System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
  at System.IO.BufferedStream.ReadByteSlow()
  at System.IO.BufferedStream.ReadByte()
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.InboundFrame.ReadFrom(Stream reader, Byte[] frameHeaderBuffer, ArrayPool`1 pool, UInt32 maxMessageSize)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ReadFrame()
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.MainLoopIteration()
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.MainLoop()
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply(TimeSpan timeout)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ConnectionStartOk(IDictionary`2 clientProperties, String mechanism, Byte[] response, String locale)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.StartAndTune()
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.StartAndTune()
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.Open(Boolean insist)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection..ctor(IConnectionFactory factory, Boolean insist, IFrameHandler frameHandler, String clientProvidedName)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection..ctor(IConnectionFactory factory, Boolean insist, IFrameHandler frameHandler, ArrayPool`1 memoryPool, String clientProvidedName)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IFrameHandler fh)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IEndpointResolver endpoints)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I have spent two days googling and troubleshooting but I am not a developer myself and couldn't find anything similar to our issue. Any help and guidance would be appreciated.

RabbitMQ version: 3.10.5
Erlang version: 24.3.4
.NET version: 6.0.10
RabbitMQ Client Library version: 6.2.1

Comment: I maintain the .NET client. Somehow your application is blocking and not completing the AMQP handshake while it runs in a container. I could easily figure this out if I can reproduce it. Any chance of providing a git repository with a Dockerfile to build and run code that reproduces this issue?